# Problems creating an MACD Strategy that will execute based to rules

Tags: python-3.x, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading, trading

I am having some issues formatting the code for an MACD strategy in **python 3** that creates a buy signal when current bars > than 2 and MACD DIFF crosses zero. I have defined the indicators and tried to make the code up below. Any help much appreciated

**Indicator definition:**

```
OHLC_DF= OHLC_DF.sort_index()
OHLC_DF['Ema_short'] = OHLC_DF['Close'].ewm(span=6,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
OHLC_DF['Ema_long'] = OHLC_DF['Close'].ewm(span=23,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
OHLC_DF['MY_MACD'] = OHLC_DF['Ema_short'] - OHLC_DF['Ema_long']

#MACD AVERAGE
OHLC_DF['MACD_AVG'] = OHLC_DF['MY_MACD'].ewm(span=9,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()

#MACDDiff = MyMACD - MACDAvg;
OHLC_DF['MACD_DIFF'] = OHLC_DF['MY_MACD'] - OHLC_DF['MACD_AVG']
```

**Trading Rules in English and attempted code:**

### Entry Trading Rules

```
CB > 2 ##check used to avoid spurious cross confirmation at CB = 2 (at CB = 1, 
  MyMACD and MACDAvg will be the same) }
If CurrentBar > 2 and MACDDiff crosses over 0 then 
    Buy ( !( "Long" ) ) next bar at market; 100% portfolio
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
##Stop out Rules
IF position(long)  and profit >$27:
            Execute 0.025 Trailing_stop (for all positions)
Else            Execute  0.048 Stop_loss 

END
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite clear from your sample what your issue is exactly. In your pseudo code you make note of the following:

```
If CurrentBar > 2

Buy ( !( "Long" ) ) next bar at market

If position(long) and profit >$27

Execute 0.025 Trailing_stop (for all positions)
```

These would be referencing objects elsewhere in your code and/or external objects from some trading platform. Based on the setup, however, it appears your buy logic may be flawed if there is no existing order logic to manage whether a LONG position is already established. Otherwise, the code will continually try to lift the offer irrespective of the available funds to purchase.

Also, I'm not sure as to the purpose of this line. I assume `CB` refers to `CurrentBar`, it would make more sense to simply denote a condition of `<= 2`

```
CB > 2 ##check used to avoid spurious cross confirmation at CB = 2 (at CB = 1, 
  MyMACD and MACDAvg will be the same) }
```